# Reverse an IP, in shell script

Tags: string, shell, unix, sh

I am looking for a simpler, more **idiomatic** and most importantly standards ([POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/mindex.html)) compliant way to reverse an IP address, using `sh` the  Unix shell.

Here's my current solution:

```bash
RevIP() {
  echo "$1"|tr . "\n"|tac|tr "\n" .
  # 'Split' on the dot character, reverse the list, 'join' with dot
}
```

Example *usage*:

```
$ RevIP 23.45.67.89
89.67.45.23.
```

*Issues*:

- this uses `tac` which is not in POSIX
- the output ends in `.` and there's no newline. Not a major problem but ideally it should end in `\n` instead.
  This could be solved by an additional `|sed s/...` at the end but is there a way to do this more elegantly so there's no need for that?

Comment: Nice, this should be an answer! @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Fair 'nuff; an answer it now is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One doesn't need external commands for this; shell builtins suffice.

```
reversed=$(echo "$ip" | { IFS=. read q1 q2 q3 q4; echo "$q4.$q3.$q2.$q1"; })
```

...or, a little more efficiently (but a little less tersely):

```
IFS=. read q1 q2 q3 q4 <<EOF
$ip
EOF
reversed="$q4.$q3.$q2.$q1"
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be one possibility for what you're looking

```
#!/bin/sh
ip="$1"
reversed=$(echo "$ip" | awk -F '.' '{print $4 "." $3 "." $2 "." $1}')
echo "$reversed"
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid `awk` but it this solution looks quite elegant 

Answer (score -2):

```
$ echo '23.45.67.89' | 
>     mawk '$!NF = sprintf((_ = "%s.%s") "." _,
>                         $(_ = NF), $--_, $--_, $--_)' FS='[.]'
89.67.45.23
```

Comment: Hmm, this works but `mawk` is not POSIX...

Comment: @ՕլՁՅԿ : it works for just about every single `awk` out there. `POSIX` purity isnt something worth adhering to.

Comment: What about [POSIX awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)? ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. : just because a spec exists doesn't mean it means jack. `gawk`'s own `posix` mode violates that spec left and right. `POSIX` is just about the worst thing that ever happened - tying everyone's hands behind their backs just so long dead `unix` variants wouldn't have their feelings hurt.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : and look how insane `gawk` is :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::::::::::::  `echo '' | gawk -e '/+++{247}*/' | gcat -n` :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `.      1     .` :::::::::::::: apparently it managed to match an ENTIRELY empty string with that `regex` - a `regex` that produced a fatal error at `mawk` `nawk` `gnu-grep` `bsd-grep` `gnu-sed` and `perl`, but `gawk` was totally cool with matching an empty string to that

Comment: POSIX isn't just useful for the past -- it means someone implementing a new coreutils alternative or libc _today_ (which there are plenty of good reasons to do -- using languages like Rust for memory-safety, f/e) has a specification they can adhere to and be judged against. It's unreasonable to ask someone writing new code to be compatible with all the cruft that's accreted onto GNU tools before what they've built is usable; having a feature-poor baseline that everyone agrees on makes it more feasible to build alternative implementations (which can then be extended after).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : `POSIX` not allowing `<<<` in shell scripts is a great example of tying people's hands behind their backs by forcing an extra (and unnecessary) `echo` or `printf` for no reason. `POSIX` allowing `<<EOFword` "here docs"  while disallowing `<<<` "here strings"/"here words" is definitely being inconsistent with itself.

Comment: There's nothing inconsistent about not including a feature if that feature wasn't present in the predecessors used as inputs to a standard but one that is included was present in those priors. That's an accident of history; it may be unfortunate, but nothing makes it hypocritical.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : so simply do nothing to update the spec to reflect …. i dunno….. a common baseline as of 10 years ago instead of as of 30 years ago ? no one should care a damn about `Ultrix` `Irix` and `SunOS 4` anymore

Comment: Yes, and the Austin Group _is_ still active, and _is_ still updating the spec. If they don't do it as fast as you like... I'm sorry? Maybe volunteer to join yourself and help improve the state of affairs. (As an example of a quality-of-life update: `find -exec ... {} +` used to be an extension rather than POSIX-mandated functionality)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : yeah "here strings" are soooooo cutting edge apparently. One site i found mentioned `<<< starting from bash 2.05b in year 2002, inspired by zsh, which had it since 1991` (`https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061`) apparently a feature already available in `bash` for nearly `21 years` is too much to ask to add to `POSIX`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : and besides, it pretty much can leverage the same parsing mechanism as here docs, but even simpler since it's delimited by `IFS` (IIRC) instead of needing the shell go hunt for that custom `EOF`. i have absolutely no idea why it's not in `POSIX`, since any `shell` that could pass here docs have already all that it needs to parse here strings - essentially a feature freebie

Comment: Please don't put technical terms in code formatting. "shell" is a noun, not a code sample (and POSIX is a proper noun as well).

Comment: Anyhow -- again, if you want faster improvement, _join the committee yourself_. Bellyaching here just wastes your time and mine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : something this obvious, if they didn't already have had the brains to recognize two sides of the same coin, plus the will to update the spec, then they never would, no matter how many committees i chair. or look at `C++` for that matter. most of the world has standardized on `UTF-8` for how long already, and only in the next `C++` draft spec did they finally make it a native data type instead of wasting everyone's time with `"wide chars"` - a concept from the `EUC` and `UCS 2` days that's no longer helpful.